# Input visibility dont change in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This program calculate the avarege of numbers. The number inputs appear according with the "input7", that represent the quantity of inputs. But for some reason the inputs dont change it visibility (They dont appear).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajuda Matemática</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css"/>
<script>
 function calcNota(){
  var input7 = document.getElementById("input7");
  if(input7.value === 1){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else if(input7.value === 2){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else if(input7.value === 3){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else if(input7.value === 4){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';     
  }
  else if(input7.value === 5){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input5").style.visibility = 'visible';   
  }
  else if(input7.value === 6){
    document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input5").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("input6").style.visibility = 'visible';    
  }
  else {
    console.log("Error");  
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="title">Ajuda Matemática</h1>
    <h2 id="subtitle">Ajuda para exercicios matemáticos<h2>
    <div class="nav">
    <ul>
     <li id="nav1"><a href="media.html">Média</a></li>
        <li id="nav2"><a href="#">Porcentagem</a></li>
        <li id="nav3"><a href="#">R. de Três</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <h2>Média</h2>       
     <input type="text" class="numE" id="input1"/>  
        <input type="text" class="numD" id="input2"/> 
         <br/>   
        <input type="text" class="numE" id="input3"/>
       <input type="text" class="numD" id="input4"/>
         <br/>   
        <input type="text" class="numE" id="input5"/> 
        <input type="text" class="numD" id="input6"/> 
         <br/>
         <br/> 
         <div id="botao">
       Quantidade de números: <input type="number" id="input7"/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <button onclick="calcNota()">Calcular</button>             
  </div>
        <h2 id="resultado">Resultado: </h2>   
        <p id="aviso">* IMPORTANTE: Escreva os valores na tabela e digite a quantidade de valores em "Quantidade de números". Também no caso de números decimais use um ponto (.) ao invés de uma vírgula (,). Do contrário resultará um erro.</p>
     </div>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inputs are already `visible`, so what is going to change?

Comment: @nmnsud I assumed the non posted CSS took care of that, but of course, that's correct.

Comment: moreover `input7.value` is `string` not `number`

Comment: @nmnsud Yes, which I already posted an answer with

Comment: @LGSon Ah! sorry I posted comment late...

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 2):

As the input value is a `String`, do like this

```
if(parseInt(input7.value) === 1){
```

or

```
if(input7.value === "1"){
```

Based on a comment, here is a sample from your code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Ajuda Matemática</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />
  <script>
    function hideInputs() {
        document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("input5").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("input6").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    function calcNota() {
        hideInputs();
        var input7 = document.getElementById("input7");
        if (input7.value === "1") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else if (input7.value === "2") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else if (input7.value === "3") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else if (input7.value === "4") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else if (input7.value === "5") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input5").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else if (input7.value === "6") {
          document.getElementById("input1").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input2").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input3").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input4").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input5").style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById("input6").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
          console.log("Error");
        }
 }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="hideInputs();">
    <div class="container">
     <h2>Média</h2> 
  <input type="text" class="numE" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" class="numD" id="input2" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="numE" id="input3" />
  <input type="text" class="numD" id="input4" />
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="numE" id="input5" />
  <input type="text" class="numD" id="input6" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="botao">
    Quantidade de números:
    <input type="number" id="input7" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="calcNota()">Calcular</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your answer. It didn't did nothing. And input7 type is set to number.

Comment: @RafaelBorges I updated my answer with a sample showing it does work

Comment: It keeps the same.

Comment: @RafaelBorges As you can see it works in this snippet, so if not in your own code you missed something from mine. Give me a link to a page and I'll have a look